# Filter an array in Python with 2 conditions

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How to filter an array A according to two conditions ?

```
A = array([1, 2.3, 4.3, 10, 23, 42, 23, 12, 1, 1])
B = array([1, 7, 21, 5, 9, 12, 14, 22, 12, 0])
print A[(B < 13)]      # here we get all items A[i] with i such that B[i] < 13
print A[(B > 5) and (B < 13)]   # here it doesn't work
                                # how to get all items A[i] such that B[i] < 13 
                                # AND B[i] > 5 ?
```

The Error is:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the *bitwise* (thanks @askewchan) version of the operator `and` which is `&`.

i.e.

```
 print A[(B > 5) & (B < 13)]
```

Comment: In numpy (and python in general), `&` isn't a _set_ operator, actually it's a _bitwise_ operator.  Here, it works only because we're comparing two `boolean` arrays as a string of bits with 1-bit elements.  It is the equivalent to saying `np.bitwise_and`, not `np.logical_and` as @larsmans has answered.  You might find the behavior unexpected if you do something like `np.array([0,1,2]) & np.array([True, True, True])`

Comment: @askewchan, thanks for your explanation. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> A[np.logical_and(B > 5, B < 13)]
array([  2.3,  23. ,  42. ,   1. ])
```